# How do I expand variables in Perl readpipe handlers?

Tags: perl, unit-testing, backticks

It seems that variables in backticks are not expanded when passed onto the readpipe function. If I override the readpipe function, how do I expand variables?

```
BEGIN {
*CORE::GLOBAL::readpipe = sub {print "Run:@_\n"};
}

`ls /root`;
my $dir = "/var";
`ls $dir`;
```

Running this gives:

```
Run:ls /root
Run:ls $dir
```

I am trying to mock external calls for a test code that I am writing. If there is a CPAN module somewhere which can help in taking care of all this, that would help too.

**Update**:

I have decided to use a really ugly workaround to my problem. It turns out that using `readpipe()` instead of backticks expands variables correctly. I am using an automatic script cleaner before running my tests which converts all backticks to `readpipe()` before running the tests.

e.g Running:

```
$ cat t.pl

BEGIN {
    *CORE::GLOBAL::readpipe = sub {print "Run:@_\n"};
}

`ls /root`;
my $dir = "/var";
`ls $dir`;
readpipe("ls $dir");
```

Gives:

```
$ perl t.pl
Run:ls /root
Run:ls $dir
Run:ls /var
```

I am still looking out for a cleaner solution though.

Answer (score 3):

That appears to be a bug in Perl. Use [perlbug](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlbug.html) to report it.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use [`IPC::Run`](http://metacpan.org/module/IPC%3a%3aRun) instead.

```
use IPC::Run 'run';

run [ "ls", $dir ], ">", \my $stdout or die "Cannot run - $!";
```

Or if you didn't want to capture the output, `system()` may be better

```
system( "ls", $dir ) == 0 or die "Cannot system - $!";
```

Comment: Thanks for the module ref. I am however looking for an easy way to mock out system calls like backticks and system() to run my unittests of a legacy code.

Comment: @SandipBhattacharya i'm sure not i understand the issue. backticks and exec do not return any output while system does. would eval and qx fit the bill?

Comment: @shinronin I am trying to override/mock backticks in existing legacy code so that I can test them safely. While I can replace the `*CORE::GLOBAL::readpipe` to mock backticks, they are not working in cases where the argument includes variables to be expanded. Because of this inconsistent behaviour between backticks and `readpipe()` it is difficult to mock such code.

I am not trying to write new code. If I did, I would have used `readpipe()` instead of backticks so that I can mock out the code if I wish.

Comment: @shinronin: you've got that partially wrong; backticks *do* provide output, while system() is silent, and exec can't return output (because the process calling it is replaced).

Comment: @jeffbragg oops, true. I can never keep them straight. perldoc -f is a constant companion. ;-)